# OpenCV - loading descriptors from yml - no matching function call

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, surf, flannbasedmatcher

I'm trying to match SURF keypoints from a template image to what is being shown in a video feed but I am getting the following errors when trying to call `FlannBasedMatcher`.

```
captureFromCam.cpp: In function ‘void matchAndDrawKeypoints(cv::Mat, IplImage*)’:
captureFromCam.cpp:110:55: error: no matching function for call to ‘cv::FlannBasedMatcher::match(cv::FileNode&, cv::Mat&, std::vector<cv::DMatch>&)’
captureFromCam.cpp:110:55: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h:68:0,
                 from captureFromCam.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp:1110:18: note: void cv::DescriptorMatcher::match(const cv::Mat&, const cv::Mat&, std::vector<cv::DMatch>&, const cv::Mat&) const
/usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp:1110:18: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘cv::FileNode’ to ‘const cv::Mat&’
/usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp:1128:18: note: void cv::DescriptorMatcher::match(const cv::Mat&, std::vector<cv::DMatch>&, const std::vector<cv::Mat>&)
/usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp:1128:18: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘cv::FileNode’ to ‘const cv::Mat&’
```

I am trying to do this by reading in the image, calculating the keypoints and descriptors and saving them in a `yml` format like so:

```
// code to detect features/descriptors
...
  cv::FileStorage fs(fileNamePostCut + ".yml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
  write(fs, fileNamePostCut + "Keypoints_1", keypoints_1);
  write(fs, fileNamePostCut + "Descriptors_1", img_descriptors_1);
  fs.release();
```

In a separate function I am then trying to load the keypoints and descriptors and compare them to the values calculated for the video stream:

```
matchAndDrawKeypoints (cv::Mat img_1, IplImage* frames)
      std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> templateKeypoints;
      std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> templateDescriptor;
      cv::FileStorage fs2("VWlogo.yml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
      cv::FileNode kptFileNode = fs2["VWlogoKeypoints_1"];
      read(kptFileNode, templateKeypoints);
      cv::FileNode desFileNode = fs2["VWlogoDescriptors_1"];
      read(desFileNode, templateDescriptor);
      fs2.release();
      cv::FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
      std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
      matcher.match(desFileNode, img_descriptors_1, matches);
```

I'm assuming the problem is either the descriptors not being loading correctly from the `yml` file or else the descriptors for the video feed are not being passed in correctly.

Below is just some extra information on the flow of information:

`main()` calls `makeitgrey(frame)` calls `detectKeypoints(grey_frame)` which returns to `makeitgrey()` which returns to `main()` which then calls `matchAndDrawKeypoints (img_1, frames)`

EDIT:
Code where keypoints are computed and declarations.

```
cv::Mat img_keypoints_1;
cv::Mat img_1;
cv::Mat img_descriptors_1;
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints_1;
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> descriptors_1;
```

`main()` passes video to `makeitgrey()` which passes to:

```
IplImage* detectKeypointsImage (IplImage* img_1) {
  int minHessian = 400;
  cv::SurfFeatureDetector detector(minHessian);
  detector.detect(img_1, keypoints_1);
  drawKeypoints(img_1, keypoints_1, img_keypoints_1);
  cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
  extractor.compute(img_1, keypoints_1, img_descriptors_1);
  return img_1;
}
```

The template image is passes in as a command line arg which is then passed to `detectTemplateKeypoints(img_1, argv[1]);` which is shown in original post.

Comment: try `matcher.match(templateDescriptor, descriptors_1, matches);` I assume that you wanted to pass the loaded descriptors to the function and not the storage file node from that you have read the descriptors already

Comment: That resulted in a very similar error. Instead of `no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘cv::FileNode’ to ‘const cv::Mat&’` I got `no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>’ to ‘const cv::Mat&’`

Comment: The loaded descriptors are to be passed to the function yes.

Comment: change `std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> templateDescriptor;` to the type that you used when writing to file node. Probably somethign like `std::vector<cv::Mat> templateDescriptor;` I mean the type of `descriptors_1` at the moment you've written it.

Comment: `std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints_1;` `std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> descriptors_1;` are the two vectors I used for writing which should be the same type? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: I am pretty sure that descriptors are not of type `cv::Keypoint`, so you might have some mistake there. I'm even pretty sure that it should be `cv::Mat` for descriptor. Can you please share the line of code where you compute the keypoints and the descriptors (including their parameter declarations)?

Comment: have a look at this example and how they declare/use descriptors during computation: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html

Comment: Hopefully that is the extra code that you asked for.

Comment: does your `detectKeypointsImage` work if you try to access the descriptors? I think it shouldn't... change to `cv::Mat descriptors_1;` and `cv::Mat templateDescriptor;` and everything should work, if I see right.

Comment: That compiles with zero errors, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If you would like to add an answer I'll gladly accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in the code:

1. `std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> templateDescriptor;` is not the right type for descriptors. For descriptor computation. In the sample code from http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html you can see, that descriptors for a bunch of keypoints are typically type `cv::Mat`. So change it to `cv::Mat templateDescriptor;` and `cv::Mat descriptors_1;`
2. `matcher.match(desFileNode, img_descriptors_1, matches);` must be `matcher.match(templateDescriptor, img_descriptors_1, matches);` instead, since you want to match the descriptors and not the file storage node.